# Tomcat 8 clustering to improve performance

Tags: tomcat

Can i  create multiple tomcat instance  in single windows server for production ? Is that a good approach to improve performance compare to multiple instance in mupltiple machine?

Comment: If the instances are sharing the same box, I don't see much point in doing that.  Anyway, Tomcat is already multi threaded, can handle multiple incoming requests, etc. AFAIK the driver behind spinning up more nodes with Tomcat isn't so much to get more instances of Tomcat, but rather more server resources.

Answer (score 0):

"Performance" is never a justification for using Tomcat *clustering*. If you want multiple instances of Tomcat (not *clustered*), then there is an argument for performance: you can throw more hardware at your users to keep them well-served.

The term *clustering* means something specific, and it actually reduces performance in nearly every case. *Clustered* Tomcat means that the instances are sharing data and updating each other between requests. You shouldn't use Tomcat *clustering* unless you have some very specific use-cases that require that e.g. users who experience a fail-over from one node to another never lose their sessions.

There are some use-cases where multiple instances of Tomcat on the same physical (or even virtual) hardware makes some sense, specifically for fault-tolerance. If your application is likely to some crashing down for one of many various reasons (e.g. OOME), then having more than one instance even on the same hardware can improve your service's reliability (as far as end-users are concerned).

But generally I think you are better served by running a single large Tomcat instance per server than multiple instances per server.

My recommendation for any production deployment would be to have at least two physical servers each running a single instance of Tomcat. (Feel free to run virtual servers on those physical machines as well... just don't put two virtual servers on a single piece of hardware and then hope that a RAM chip doesn't fail and bring both of them down). That allows you to bring one of them down for maintenance while the others remain up and serving requests. You can march through your set of Tomcat nodes, performing whatever maintenance is required and then bring them back into the load-balancer.

Oh, and you are going to need a load-balancer :)